# Can't use Ubuntu fonts in PHP script using exec() function because of permission/ownership

Tags: command-line, permissions, php, fonts

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 Server 64-bit VPS and I want to use `XeLaTeX` to create PDF files with desired fonts. I have installed fonts and `XeLaTex` works fine if I execute it from terminal:

```
xelatex sample.tex
```

And it produces sample.pdf without any problem. But if I execute the same command from PHP `exec()` function like the following command:

```
$cmd = "cd folder && xelatex sample.tex";

$excute  = shell_exec($cmd);
```

I'll face 'font is not found' problem. Because everything is OK, I think the problem is with fonts permissions or ownership. I tried to change the permission of a specific font folder and files to `744` and even tried to change the ownership to one who owns the PHP file but I couldn't fix the problem. I don't want to use `sudo` to execute the command because of security concerns.

How should I make Ubuntu fonts available to PHP script?

**Update 1:**

Here is my sample.tex file, I use settextfont to select fonts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}    
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{mathrsfs}    
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage[top=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}    
\usepackage{xepersian}    
\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{XB Yas}    
\setdigitfont{XB Yas}

\begin{document}    
    Hello, This is a test file.
\end{document}
```

**Update 2:**

I changed the code to the following one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}    
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{mathrsfs}    
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage[top=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}   
\setmainfont{Yas}[Path = /var/www/html/fonts/,UprightFont = *-Rg,Extension = .ttf]

\begin{document}    
    Hello, This is a test file.
\end{document}
```

But now I face the following error:

```
fontspec error: "font-not-found"

The font "Yas-Rg" cannot be found.
```

There are Yas-Rg.ttf, Yas-Bd.ttf and other fonts in /var/www/html/fonts and the ownership has been set to one who owns the PHP script and also permissions have been set to 774.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `fontspec` package, and according to the [fontspec package documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) (page 9), you should be able to place the desired fonts in a folder where apache get the correct rights:

```
To load a font that is not in one of the default search paths, its 
location in the filesystem must be specified with the Path feature:

\setmainfont{texgyrepagella}[
    Path           = /var/www/myProject/Fonts/ ,
    UprightFont    = *-regular ,
    BoldFont       = *-bold ,
... ]
```

Comment: I still have problem selecting fonts. See my Update 2 please.